# Correct quoting in Perl OpenSSH module to parse an MySQL command

Tags: perl

I am using the [Net::OpenSSH Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH-0.57/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm) module to connect to an SSH server and perform the following code:

```
my @cmd = 'mysql -e "SET GLOBAL general_log_file = $log"';
$ssh->system(@cmd);
```

Here is the correct shell command:

```
mysql -e "SET GLOBAL general_log_file = 'log_name'"
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

You see that my problem is how to parse the variable correctly.

Could you please help me to correct the quoting? I have already tried all possible variants.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cmd should be a really be defined as a scalar, not a list.  Since you are replacing `$log` within the string, you should open with double quotes and wrap within single quotes for mysql:

```
my $cmd = "mysql -e \"SET GLOBAL general_log_file = '$log'\"";
$ssh->system($cmd);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a list, not a scalar, unlike the advice of answer 1, but it shouldn't be an array of one element.

```
my @cmd = (mysql => '-e',  "SET GLOBAL general_log_file = '$log'");
$ssh->system(@cmd);
```

see [Shell Quoting](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-OpenSSH/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm#Shell_quoting) in Net::OpenSSH documentation.

Note that this assumes that the $log variable doesn't contain any characters of special meaning to SQL, like *'*

Finding a way to connect to your Mysql server with DBI (perhaps using Net::OpenSSH's opentunnel) and using a prepared statment with a placeholder to run this command would be better.